# Should I use UUID or something else?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, join, uuid

Very often I have a task, where I need to collect an object and I need to know it's ID before saving to DB (PostgreSQL).

I can do this with UUID but it has lots of disadvantages:
- less perfomance when selecting or including
- less perfomance with joins
- need more space

**So question is:** How can I generate an ID for the object beforehand and minimize UUID negative consequences?

Comment: Why not let the database assign a `serial` id?  That works in lots and lots and lots of databases.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: +@GordonLinoff And just use `INSERT ... RETURNING id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We faced this issue with a project. I ran some tests (about 4M rows, if I remember right) which indicated that uuids didn't really hit PG's performance too badly compared with ints. Having used uuids as primary keys for some time now I wouldn't hesitate to do so again. Although, I must add the caveat we have yet to see how this performs in production on a large scale.

Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database

The nice thing about using uuids is you never have to worry about clashes. Not nice thing: they are a bit cumbersome if you're manually entering a query for a test.

If you end up selecting based on a large list of uuids use this trick: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/

Hope this helps,

Adam.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any uuid generator in whatever programming language to do this.  I would suggest using the uuid type in PostgreSQL to avoid the need for too much overhead regarding space or joining.  PostgreSQL also does not include a way of generating these so you have to generate them first.

A major issue you may run into is that with numeric ids, a number of things are relatively painless that become a bigger issue with uuids.  These include:

1. Typing in identifiers
2. Selecting a series of records inserted at a similar time (because numeric ids are sequential).

However if you use the UUID type in PostgreSQL, selection and join performance should not be too bad. And how you generate the UUIDs is up to you as a programmer

Answer (score 0):

Of course the UUID should works in low performance than integer, the question is on which volume of data. To be honestly, 4M data is too small to say whether it will be performance issue, and of course, if the requirements image that the data volume is still less than 4M, that is OK.

In the document https://rclayton.silvrback.com/do-you-really-need-a-uuid-guid , it suggest better on how and when to use UUID